# If you compiled C/Go/Rust or any other compiled language is that not just AOT compilation and if not what is the difference?

Tags: compilation, aot

If you compiled any language that is natively compilable is that not considered AOT compilation. As you are literally compiling it ahead of time from when you want to run it, so I am confused as to why people don't say that C/Go are AOT compiled. Or is there something I am missing?

Comment: Some people do say that C/Go are AOT compiled. See, for instance, the wikipedia article: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ahead-of-time_compilation I think you hear the term AOT in reference to interpreted languages because they did not always have this feature. By contract, C has always been compiled "ahead of time". So, normally you just say C is compiled and everyone knows what you mean.

Comment: Cool that makes sense. But then is a java jar file not AOT?

Comment: java jar files are mainly about collecting files into a single bundle for easier deployment (among other benefits). I don't think there is any compilation (in the sense of compiling source code into code ready for execution). https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JAR_(file_format)

Comment: Awesome thanks. But I am still confused about what AOT then is for interpreted languages.